# Finding a laurent series of $f$ with centre $1$ and converges *at* $3$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z) = \frac{1}{z-2i} - \frac{1}{z+i}$.

I tried doing this:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z-1+1-2i} - \frac{1}{z-1+1+i}$$

So I want to manipulate this to somehow allow the radius of convergence to include $3$ in that ball of convergence.
However, I'm not sure where to go from here, as manipulating and applying the GP formulae, I'd just get regions such as $0<|z-1|<\sqrt{2}$ which doesn't include the point $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s the trick that I use, handling the two fractions separately:
First,
\begin{align}
\frac1{z-1+1-2i}&=\frac{1/(1-2i)}{1+(z-1)/(1-2i)}\\
&=\frac1{1-2i}\left[1-\frac{z-1}{1-2i}+\frac{(z-1)^2}{(1-2i)^2}-\cdots\right]\\
&=\frac1{1-2i}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(1-2i)^n}(z-1)^n\right]\,.
\end{align}
Next,
\begin{align}
\frac1{z-1+1+i}&=\frac{1/(z-1)}{1+(1+i)/(z-1)}\\
&=\frac1{z-1}\left[1-\frac{1+i}{z-1}+\frac{(1+i)^2}{(z-1)^2}-\cdots\right]\\
&=\frac1{z-1}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(1+i)^n}{(z-1)^n}\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1-i)^n(z-1)^{-n-1}\,.
\end{align}
Here, for the very first step, I’ve divided top and bottom by $1-2i$ for the first problem, and by $z-1$ for the second problem. When $z=3$, the common ratios of these geometric series have absolute values, respectively, $2/\sqrt5$ and $\sqrt2/2$, both comfortably less than $1$, good for convergence.